# Checking for the type of a decorated class in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai, typescript-decorator

If we define a decorator function like this:

```
  return function IsDefined(object: any, propertyName: string) {
       ....
  ]
```

Then decorate some property like this:

```
class Test {
  @IsDefined() p1: String = "";
}
```

And execute this test inside the decorator:

```
  expect(object).to.equal(Test);
```

Should it pass?  What is `object`?

This for example passes:

```
const instance:any = new Test();

expect(object.constructor.name).
to.equal(instance.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first argument of property decorator is always current instance of the class or constructor for static members. So in this case `object` would be `Test` class instance decorator is called from.

This test shouldn't pass cause as I mentioned it's current instance. You can check if object is actually instance of `Test` or similar to your last example:

```
expect(object instanceof Test).toBeTruthy();
```

or

```
expect(object.constructor.name).toBe('Test');
```